# Why does echo print only one value from PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got the following code:

```
$comments = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT * FROM `ycommentbox` WHERE `url`='".$id."'");
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment;
}
```

which echoes:

> "test121677129055"

"ycomemntbox" structure:

[image: three rows]

Why isn't it echoing the other 2 rows but just the first one?

It should echo this:

> "test121677129055"
>   "test221677129056"
>   "test321677129057"

Comment: Have you tried `var_export($comments);` to see the data structured being returned by `QueryFetchArray`?  What does the result look like?

Comment: `QueryFetchArray()` is not a standard function, so we do not know what it returns. It may fetch one row, or maybe many.

Answer (score 1):

Because `QueryFetchArray` only returns a single row; it's only an array because it includes all the column values from that row.

To get all the rows, you need to either do `QueryFetchAll` to get them in one big array, or do an initial `Query` followed by `FetchArray` in a loop that will run once per row.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

And your id wants to match with this query :

```
 $comments = $db->QueryFetchAll("SELECT * FROM `ycommentbox` WHERE `url`='".$id."'");
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        echo $comment;
    }
```

OR you can change this query like this

```
$comments = $db->QueryFetchAll("SELECT * FROM `ycommentbox`");
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            echo $comment;
        }
```

Comment: You're missing a " in the second example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print_r` for multiple values
and use `echo` for single value ok
 **OR:**
If you use only `echo` then use echo & tr td html tags between `""`.
Write starting tags in `""` and `.$variable`. and again end tags between `""

Comment: Can you give an example?  It's a little difficult to visualize what your are trying to describe.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For loop looks ok, so I can suggest first to make a {echo count($comments);}  to check actually how many rows returned by the query.  It will validate the query first.